# How to prove some conditional probability properties?

Tags: probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

How to prove that(given that any conditioning event
has probability $> 0$):

1.IF $\mathbb{P}(B)=1$, then $\mathbb{P}(A|B) = \mathbb{P}(A)$ for any $A$

Here, its obvious that  $\mathbb{P}(A)$ is always in the subset of $\mathbb{P}(B)$ and thus occurs with $\mathbb{P}(A)=1$ as well. I just dont know how to express that mathematically.

2. If $A \subset B$, then $\mathbb{P}(B|A)=1$ and $\mathbb{P}(A|B)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(A)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}$

Here I just would think similarly.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb P(A\mid B)$ is defined so that: $$\mathbb P(A\cap B)=\mathbb P(A\mid B)\;\mathbb P(B)$$

From this everything you seek will follow.

> > 1.IF $\mathbb{P}(B)=1$, then $\mathbb{P}(A\mid B) = \mathbb{P}(A)$ for any $A$
>
> Here, its obvious that  $\mathbb{P}(A)$ is always in the subset of $\mathbb{P}(B)$

No, what is obvious is that $A$ is the subset of $B$, because $B$ is the total space (a.s.).

> and thus occurs with $\mathbb{P}(A)=1$ as well. I just dont know how to express that mathematically.

No, $A\subseteq B$ means that $\;\Bbb P(A)\leq \Bbb P(B)\;$.   However, more relevantly (to the problem at hand) it also means that: $$A = A\cap B$$

---

> > 2. If $A \subset B$, then $\mathbb{P}(B\mid A)=1$ and $\mathbb{P}(A\mid B)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(A)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}$

Second verse, same as the first.   Substitute what you are given into the definition of conditional probability, then simplify.

Comment: @ Graham. Thank you for these hints. I just nit fully sure about the second verse. You man I just have to substitute $A=A \cap B$ into the C.P. def.?

Comment: Yes, @Googme . Also use that $\Bbb P(A\cap B) = \Bbb P(A)\,\Bbb P(B\mid A)$